# Data inserted in two different rows

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ms-access

I'm trying to insert a raw data and a time stamp into the database. both the data and timestamp have to be in one row. However, when saved, they seem to be inserted into two different cells, two different rows as in the picture.

[image]

The code is written in visual basic along with asp.net.

```
Dim cn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= "& Server.MapPath("dbase/DB.mdb"))

    Protected Sub btnUSsave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUSsave.Click

        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("insert into Quest(US1)values(@a1)", cn)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("a1", TextBox1.Text)

        Dim time1 As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Quest(TimeUS1) VALUES (Time())", cn)

        cn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        time1.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cn.Close()

        Response.Redirect("CountryA2Desc.aspx")

    End Sub
```

Any idea on how to make the data in one row ?

Comment: You are executing two `INSERT` statements so of course you insert two rows. If you want to insert one row then execute one `INSERT` statement. The alternative would be one `INSERT` and one `UPDATE` but why do that when one `INSERT` with both values is easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, you just need to use one insert statement instead of two. This should work for you

```
Protected Sub btnUSsave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUSsave.Click

    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("insert into Quest(US1,TIMEUS1) values(@a1,Time())", cn)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("a1", TextBox1.Text)

    cn.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cn.Close()

    Response.Redirect("CountryA2Desc.aspx")

End Sub
```